# Using PHP to Seperate Results of a txt file

Tags: php, newline, text-files

I am trying to display the last 10 lines of a File and from there take those results and break them down to 10 individual lines..

Currently the code I have found from examples is:

```
$filearray = file("test.txt");
$lastfifteenlines = array_slice($filearray,-10);

echo implode($lastfifteenlines, "\n")
```

It display's the 10 items I need however it does not break them down onto individual lines the current results are:

```
1.0.0.11 1.0.0.12 1.0.0.13 1.0.0.14 1.0.0.15
```

I need that to instead display as:

```
1.0.0.11 
1.0.0.12 
1.0.0.13 
1.0.0.14 
1.0.0.15
```

Thanks in Advance for the Asistance!

Comment: could you improve your expected display?  those two lines look the same to me.

Comment: Your current result and what you want to get look th same. Use code tags.

Comment: is the final output for this a website or a terminal screen? with a website you should be using '<br />' instead of "\n" for the newlines to appear.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is plain whitespace in html.

use `echo implode("<br>", $lastfifteenlines)` or put them in to separate `div`s, use a list (`ul`+`li`), etc..

Answer (score 0):

use the `explode` function, like this

```
$filearray = file("test.txt");
$lastfifteenlines = array_slice($filearray,-10);
$impfile = implode($lastfifteenlines, '\n');
$lines = explode('\n', $impfile);

foreach ($lines as $line){
    echo $line."<br>";
}
```

outpu will be

```
1.0.0.11 
1.0.0.12 
1.0.0.13 
1.0.0.14 
1.0.0.15
```

i hope that's what you want :)

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine. You just can't see the line breaks because HTML doesn't treat them as line breaks.

See the HTML source code in your browser to see the line breaks.

### Possible solution

- echo `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags before and after the implode.
- Add `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` before any output. It will cause the browser to parse the document as a text file and not HTML (note that no HTML tags will be parsed by the browser)
- implode the array with a different string, `<br>`, which will cause a line break in HTML.

---

Also, your syntax is wrong, it's

```
implode($glue, $pieces);
```

And not

```
implode($pieces, $glue);
```

Comment: You're assuming that the output is being viewed on a webpage, and your syntax criticism is wrong. implode can take the parameters in either order.

Comment: @H Hatfield: that's a perfectly valid assumption based on the question... on a terminal that code would work.

Comment: @HHatfield that's kinda the only option... And also, just because it can be done in a specific way (which goes against the docs) doesn't mean it's correct. The syntax is wrong, even if it works.